# In Phonegap, HTML does not resize with app is rotated

Tags: ios, html, cordova

I have a Phonegap iPhone/iPad application, and when I rotate the iPad application to landscape, its like the thing does not refresh the HTML/CSS, so I'm stuck with a black bar on the right of the application. Same thing, if I open the app in landscape it looks fine, but then rotate to portrait, it requires scrolling.

Comment: Did you try it on the device? Because I've used phonegap to do Android apps and it rotated normally. Maybe it's a problem on the emulator.

Comment: Yes, I actually had to publish a emergency update to my iOS apps, because people were getting stuck in the landscape mode on iPad and then they had to scroll.

Answer (score 7):

I had to remove height=device-height from my meta tag and it fixed it. Thanks to all those who assisted me!